# Python program to get count of a string in an excel file

Tags: python

I have a requirement to search 2 columns(B and C) in excel file to see if they contain a particular word as part of excel cell value and return the count of number of times that word is present.

Comment: Welcome to SO, this is not a code writing service. What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this first by saving the Excel file to CSV - comma separated variable.  This will be a lot easier to read in your python script and Excel the application can do this by default.

Then, I would read the file line by line, split it on commas, and search the second and third values for the word you are looking for.

```
with open('my.csv', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        columns = line.split(',')
        if TARGET in columns[1] or TARGET in columns[2]:
            count += 1
print("The count of %s in columns B & C is: %d" % (TARGET, count))
```